# How to solve a difference equation with starting and end condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I am currently having trouble solving a difference equations problem where the initial value is given and the end value. I simplified the problem to the following:
\begin{align}
y^{k - 1} - 2y^{k} + y^{k+1} = 0, \qquad k=1, \dots, T-1, y^{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \text{ for } i\in [0, \dots, T], 
\end{align}
where the values for $y^{0}$ and $y^{T}$ are given. I have tried googling but the only thing I found are examples where $y^{0}$ and $y^{1}$ are known, which is not case here sadly.

**Question:** Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks for any help or tips in advance!

Comment: can't you  leave one of the parameters (the value for $y_1$) free and determine it so as to get the required value for $y_T$ ?

Comment: Let you have solution from $y_0$ and $y_1$ in the form $y_i(y_0,y_1)$, then you can solve equation $y_T(y_0,y_1)=y_T$ for $y_1$ and then put it into $y_i(y_0,y_1)$ to get solution in terms of $y_0$ and $y_T$.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, you can rewrite your relationship as $y^{k-1} - y^k = y^k - y^{k+1}$, so for every $i$ the quantity $y^i - y^{i+1}$ is the same. Now note that
$$
y^0 = y^T + \sum_{i=0}^{T-1}y^i - y^{i+1}.
$$
Can you conclude from there?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I would like to ask a follow up question (I am unsure if I should do a seperate post). How would you solve
\begin{align}
y_{k-1} - 2y_{k} + y_{k+1} = A y_{k} + B(y_{k-1} - y_{k+1})
\end{align}
where $A$ is symmetric positive definite and $B$ is antisymmetric. The rest is defined as before. Thanks in advance for tips and help.

Comment: @Peter, I suggest you ask a separate question (possibly linking this one). That question is much harder!

Answer (score 3):

If the difference between consecutive terms is constant, you have an arithmetic sequence, which has the form $y^k = ak+b$.  We have that
$$y^0 = b \implies y^k = ak+y^0.$$
Now, to find $a$,
$$y^T = aT+y^0 \implies a = \frac{y^T-y^0}{T}.$$
Hence, the solution is
$$y^k = y^0 + \frac{y^T-y^0}{T}k.$$

Comment: actually the second difference is null, so your answer is right

Comment: @Doug Thanks for the response! I would like to ask a follow up question (I am unsure if I should do a seperate post). How would you solve
\begin{align}
y_{k-1} - 2y_{k} + y_{k+1} = A y_{k} + B(y_{k-1} - y_{k+1})
\end{align}
where $A$ is symmetric positive definite and $B$ is antisymmetric. The rest is defined as before. Thanks in advance for tips and help.

Comment: @Peter, I cannot say.  I'm definitely not expert in recurrences, and this appears much more complex.  I would search on the site, and if you can't find anything, ask as a separate post.