# How to solve a recurrence with starting and end condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

2 days ago I asked a simplified version of the question below, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4490627/how-to-solve-a-difference-equation-with-starting-and-end-condition/4490633?noredirect=1#comment9421287_4490633). However, I simplified the question too much and I am now stuck with the following problem:
\begin{align}
y^{k-1} - 2y^{k} + y^{k+1} = A y^{k} + B(y^{k-1} - y^{k+1}), \quad y^{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{d},  k = 1, \dots, T-1
\end{align}
where $A$ is symmetric positive definite and $B$ is antisymmetric. Furthermore, the values for $y^{0}$ and $y^{T}$ are given. I haven't found any source in google on how to solve such a problem.

**Question:** How does one solve such a problem? Numerical solutions are also fine.

Thanks in advance for tips and help.

Comment: Do you have a concrete application in mind? Note that all these equations are just one big linear system in $(T-1)d$ free variables, so at least in principle you can always find the solutions using regular linear algebra techniques, if $T$ and $d$ are not too large.

Comment: @MeesdeVries In my case, I have $T=10$ and $d \in \{1, 2, 3\}$. I am unsure how to transform the problem I described into a form such that I can plug it into a solver in python that uses regular linear algebra techniques. How would you do that?

Comment: Do you see that you can rewrite all of your equations/constraints into one big matrix-vector equation $Mv = 0$, where $v$ contains all your unknowns (i.e. $y^i_j$ for $0 < i < T$ and $1 \leq j \leq d$)? If not, would you be able to rewrite $a + 2b = 0, 3a - b = 0$ into a matrix-vector equation form?

Comment: @MeesdeVries Thanks a lot. I think I understand now how to get to matrix-vector notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

With $y_0,y_4$ given, we can solve this as a linear system

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -(A+2 I) & B+I & 0 \\
 I-B & -(A+2 I) & B+I \\
 0 & I-B & -(A+2 I)\\
\end{array}
\right)\left(\matrix{y_1\\ y_2\\ y_3}\right) = \left(\matrix{-(I-B)y_0\\ 0\\ -(B+I)y_4}\right) 
$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But shouldn't it be $-(I-B)y_{0}$ and $-(B+I)y_{4}$ on the right-hand side of the equation?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to change sign. Thanks.